# Save an Image Under Drawable Into Storage

Tags: android

I have a png file under my drawable folder and I want to save it into some folder in my physical device.

I already have write permissions and everything, but I can't always do what I want. Interesting thing is if I try 10 times to save the image, it somehow manages twice, not more.

I am using LG 3, Android 5.0, API 21. When I tried yesterday it didn't save the image however today when I was looking through the gallery I saw the image..

I also managed to save the image in the emulator with API 22 but never with API 24.

This is the code:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ShareActivity.this,new String[] {android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);

Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.instagram_logo);

File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();


File dir = new File(path + "/savehere/");
if(!dir.exists())
{
    dir.mkdirs();
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Directory already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


File file = new File(dir,"photo.png");

OutputStream out = null;

try
{
    out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,80,out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();

}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: `dir.mkdirs();` Check the return value as it might fail to create a directory. If so display a toast to the user and return. It does not make much sense to continue if  you want to place a file in a directory that not exists.

Comment: Put Toast()'s in those catch blocks so the user of your app is informed about those exceptions. ... And you too...

Comment: `I was looking through the gallery I saw the image.` Wrong. You should not use the Gallery app to check if your file is created. Completely wrong. You should use a File Explorer app and look in that directory.

Comment: The Gallery app will only show your image after reboot.

Comment: I rebooted my phone but I couldn't get any newly created directories. Creating a directory is not completely necessary in fact. What is your opinion let's say I want to download images to Pictures folder? Would it be sufficient to edit the code like 
`File file = new File(directory_of_Pictures_folder,"photo.png");` ? Without getting into directory creation?

Comment: Of course that is ok. But you have not reacted on what i said about mkdirs() and the empty catch blocks. Unfriendly. Especially when you cannot find those directories. So mkdirs() failed.  For that you did not have to reboot of course.

Comment: And if you cannot create a directory you will also not be able to create a file in the Pictures directory.

Comment: I didn't mean to offend you, I am trying to implement what you said right now in parallel. I downloaded file explorer app and I can see an image created just now, successfully. But even though I rebooted the phone it doesn't appear in the gallery app. I checked its path and it is storage/emulated/0/savehere/ , just like in my code above. What do you think about this? Would it cause any problems if I would want to read this image from memory this time?

EDIT: Oh, now it appears in Gallery. Why now ? :)

Comment: If the path is /storage/emulated/0/savehere/mypicture.jpg you will be able to read it. It's strange that the Gallery app does not show it after reboot. Maybe tomorrow ;-). If you want the Gallery app to immediately know about the new file you schould let the MediaStore scan the file. Two lines of code extra. Search for scanning a file and so. This problem has been on stackoverflow so many times already.

Comment: `EDIT: Oh, now it appears in Gallery. Why now ?` After reboot the media scanner is invoked. Of course it cannot scan your whole device in a couple of seconds.

Comment: My code is actually working except the fact that refreshing gallery instantly! Downloading File Explorer made things clear!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have the write permission in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You need to check whether the external storage is available which might be an sd card. Check for that.

```
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
 String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
  if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
     return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Once that is done, get a location to actually store the file using the following function.

```
String filename = "SampleFile.png";
String filepath = "MyFileStorage";
File myExternalFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(filepath), filename);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myExternalFile);
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,80,fos);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Code borrowed from [Android External Storage – Read, Write, Save File](https://www.journaldev.com/9400/android-external-storage-read-write-save-file) and [Saving Files Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Comment: What is myExternalFile in your case?

Comment: @ConiSayns Its the File object that holds the reference to a file called SampleFile.txt inside the folder called MyFileStorage,

Comment: And what about inputText ? @Jude

Comment: @ConiSayns I edited my answer, i forgot to make changes to the code that i took,you wont need the edit text instead you can use your existing code for the part where you write to the file and also remember to name the file with a .png or .jpeg or any other extension used to store images.

Comment: `You need to check whether the external storage is available which might be an sd card.` That was a hundred years ago. External storage is always there. Removable storage as an SD card is something different.

Comment: `isExternalStorageWritable()` Writable? You are checking mounted only.